# Sql Query to Find the teams who have played all tournaments?

Tags: mysql, database

My schema is:

1. country(countryName**(Primary Key)**)
2. tournament(year,date) having **composite primary key (year,date)**
3. team(ID,Year,Country) having **composite PK (ID,year,Country)**

**Data in Tournament table is:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tournament` (
  `Year` date NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tournament` (`Year`, `Country`) VALUES
('2015-12-17', 'Canada'),
('2015-12-17', 'USA'),
('2016-12-17', 'Canada'),
('2016-12-17', 'USA'),
('2017-12-17', 'UK'),
('2017-12-17', 'USA'),
('2018-12-17', 'China'),
('2018-12-17', 'USA'),
('2019-12-17', 'Australia'),
('2019-12-17', 'USA');

ALTER TABLE `tournament`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Year`,`Country`),
  ADD KEY `country_tournament_FK` (`Country`);

ALTER TABLE `tournament`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `country_tournament_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`Country`) REFERENCES `country` (`Name`);
COMMIT;
```

**Data in Team's Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `Year` date NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `team` (`Year`, `ID`, `Country`) VALUES
('2015-12-17', 6, 'Australia'),
('2016-12-17', 2, 'Canada'),
('2019-12-17', 1, 'China'),
('2016-12-17', 1, 'UK'),
('2017-12-17', 2, 'UK'),
('2015-12-17', 5, 'USA'),
('2016-12-17', 5, 'USA'),
('2017-12-17', 5, 'USA'),
('2018-12-17', 5, 'USA'),
('2019-12-17', 5, 'USA');

ALTER TABLE `team`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Year`,`ID`),
  ADD KEY `team_country_fk` (`Country`);

ALTER TABLE `team`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `team_country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Country`) REFERENCES `country` (`Name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `team_tournament_fk_final` FOREIGN KEY (`Year`) REFERENCES `tournament` (`Year`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

I want to select those teams who have played all tournaments(mean in all years 2015 to 2019)? Stuck on this query, i'm a student looking for a solution to this query so please let me know either its possible or not any good clue?

Comment: what i think is that i can get the result from tournament table only, any solution if possible?

Comment: Please post your table data as formatted text, not images. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: A few things first. You say you are using country name as a primary key but countries are repeated in both tables, your primary key should be unique across each table. Wouldn't it be easier to only store the year instead of the entire date? From what I understand the month and day don't matter. For clarity I would also rename country in the tournaments table to 'Host' or something.

Comment: i used country in other tables as foreign key.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya please check,i've edited the question

Comment: Can you think of a query that finds teams that haven't played at least one tournament?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if id is an autonumber and you have only 1 team per country.

```
select country    
from team
group by country
having Count(*)=(select count(distinct year) from tournament)
```

If id is an id of a team and you have another table "team" where id is a foreign key to this table, you have something like this

```
select team.id
from team
group by team.id
having Count(*)=(select count(*) from tournament)
```

Comment: You are close but the answer is not right. You will need to check for distinct count,

Comment: Kristjan Kica sir much appreciated, thanks alot for giving me idea, you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be a simple

```
SELECT X FROM Y WHERE CONDITION_1 AND CONDITION_2
```

In your case, you would have something like:

```
SELECT Country FROM team WHERE Year >= 2015-12-17 AND Year <= 2019-12-17
```

The query means:

*Select rows from the 'Country' column located in the 'team' table that meet the condition of 'Year' being a value between 2015-12-17 and 2019-12-17.*

There are many results on google if you look for "SQL Date Range" or similar stuff. There are also other ways to solve your problem, for example using the `BETWEEN` operation.